# How to write condition better and faster

Tags: c#, refactoring

I refactor old code and I dont know what to do about this part of code.
I need this code to be fastest code of the most fastest codes ever been seen. :D No I just want to know if there is some better writing style of for this situation.

I have main class(main). On main class I have asociated class  in 7 relations (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) In these classes are exept other these two attributes: (datetime1, datetime2). And my goal is to check if any of this attriutes in these relation changed, and if changed run method that changes that current attribute in different (second_main) class. But this attribute asociation cannot be same on these (main and second_main) classes. (Means that a.datetime1 cannot be same relation as b.datetime1 because b.datetime1 could change without any update on a.datetime1. But when a.datetime1 changes it must change b.datetime1.

Maybe I write it little bit too complicated. So please be patient.

This version is not much readable and I think, it could be written much better. I've tried lambda expression, but the list initialization may take a long of time and the

```cs
(!this.a.IsNull("datetime1") && this.a.IsChanged("datetime1")) ||
(!this.b.IsNull("datetime1") && this.b.IsChanged("datetime1")) ||
(!this.c.IsNull("datetime1") && this.c.IsChanged("datetime1")) ||
(!this.d.IsNull("datetime1") && this.d.IsChanged("datetime1")) ||
(!this.e.IsNull("datetime1") && this.e.IsChanged("datetime1")) ||
(!this.f.IsNull("datetime1") && this.f.IsChanged("datetime1")) ||
(!this.g.IsNull("datetime1") && this.g.IsChanged("datetime1")) ||
(!this.a.IsNull("datetime2") && this.a.IsChanged("datetime2")) ||
(!this.b.IsNull("datetime2") && this.b.IsChanged("datetime2")) ||
(!this.c.IsNull("datetime2") && this.c.IsChanged("datetime2")) ||
(!this.d.IsNull("datetime2") && this.d.IsChanged("datetime2")) ||
(!this.e.IsNull("datetime2") && this.e.IsChanged("datetime2")) ||
(!this.f.IsNull("datetime2") && this.f.IsChanged("datetime2")) ||
(!this.g.IsNull("datetime2") && this.g.IsChanged("datetime2"))
{
   DejAtributDoCasti("a.datetime1",
                     "b.datetime1",
                     "c.datetime1",
                     "d.datetime1",
                     "e.datetime1",
                     "f.datetime1",
                     "g.datetime1",
                     "a.datetime2",
                     "b.datetime2",
                     "c.datetime2",
                     "d.datetime2",
                     "e.datetime2",
                     "f.datetime2",
                     "g.datetime2");
}
```

Comment: When you say "*faster*", you mean "*faster to write*" or "*faster to execute*"? If the former, Patrick Hofman's solution seems quite good. If the latter, I don't think there is a faster way to execute this

Comment: Also maybe you could have your seven relations stored in an array to begin with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ here:

```
var list = new[] { a, b, c, ... };

if (list.Any(l => !l.IsNull("datetime1") && l.IsChanged("datetime1"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Some of the clauses need different keys, e.g. `datetime2`

Comment: Well, then you can edit the lambda. `!l.IsNull("datetime1") && l.IsChanged("datetime1") || !l.IsNull("datetime2") && l.IsChanged("datetime2")`, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but doesnt lambda list initialization be slower on execution. Because everytime something changes it must create new list with (a,b,c,d,e...)

Comment: Yes, the execution is a little slower indeed. As long as you don't call this a million times in a tight loop, you will be okay. You could cache the list if possible.

Comment: Okay, I try stopwatch new lambda execution and check if the result is faster. :) Thank you